# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, nvm

When I try to run the `yarn install`, the command doesn't seem to run instead it throws a error as shown in below

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
Require stack:
- /Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js
- /Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/yarn.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.fs/promises (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:16716:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:17137:42)
    at Module../sources/fsUtils.ts (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:16033:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:17137:42)
    at Module../sources/corepackUtils.ts (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:15738:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js:17137:42) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js',
    '/Users/sakrishnas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/yarn.js'
  ]
}
```

[image]

This seems to happen after the mac OS monetery update. I tried uninstalling xcode and reinstalling, removed node and nvm completely and reinstalled again.
Node version: `12.16.3`

Can anyone help me to fix this error.